# Tableau TABCMD download workbook by giving only project name

Tags: tableau-api

I wanted to download all workbook from project without changing it's format using Tabcmd utility. Format can be **TWB or TWBX**.

is there any option i can get either **FORMAT or WORKBOOK URL or BOTH** of all tableau workbook by giving Project name, so that i can download it as backup.

I do not wanted to use POSTGRES or Tableau REST APIs. I am in need of batch script only.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of downloading all workbooks from a project using tabcmd without knowing all of the workbook names.

Although you've said you don't want use it, the REST API is the best way of doing this.

Comment: Yeah, for workaround I have used Tableau REST API. Thanks @Talvalin